# Class compilation requires too much metadata?

Tags: apex, compile-error

Can anybody let me know when/why I get this error:

> Compile Error: Class compilation requires too much metadata. Please consider splitting this class into multiple classes

Comment: There should be a badge for reaching this limit :) I'm wondering how many lines of code you have ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can write only 1 million character per class and your class character count is greater then this so you need to break it into multiple sub classes.

[image]

[Size-Specific Apex Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)

Comment: I just checked the number of characters. It is 17k char.

Comment: @AmitVisapurkar check for method size and complete org code coverage.